# ffmpeg: what rate to set in this example

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm compiling a video with ffmpeg, multiple images and a wav file.
It gets compiled properly, but images seem to end before the wav finishes. Basically the last few frames are blank.
Is there a calculation I can apply to set frame rate etc, so that this does not happen?
Wav duration: 60 seconds
Number of images: 175
command used:

```
ffmpeg -r 5 -i img%d.jpg -i audio.wav -r 30 video.mov
```

what rates should I use here?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you need 175 images to fill 60s, so you should probably be using:

```
ffmpeg -r 5 -i img%d.jpg -i audio.wav -r 175/60 video.mov
```

Comment: Hi, then what is the significance of the -r before input files? If I reduce that while keeping the second -r same, the video slows down.

Comment: -4 before input files specifies how much time ffmpeg should interpret each .jpg file to represent (here, each is 1/5 th of a second)...